# How to make GCC reduce 'arg,##__VA_ARGS__' to 'arg' to use it as single macro argument?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I have these macros defined for visual studio and clang and they both compile fine

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define _declare_func(...) PP_CAT(PP_CAT(_declare_func_, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)),(__VA_ARGS__))
#   define declare_func(...) _declare_func PP_LEFT_PAREN notused,##__VA_ARGS__ PP_RIGHT_PAREN
#else // clang version
#   define _declare_func(...) PP_CAT(_declare_func_, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#   define declare_func(...) _declare_func ( notused,##__VA_ARGS__ )
#endif

#define _declare_func_1(notused)               void my_function()
#define _declare_func_2(notused, scope)        void scope::my_function()

class MyClass 
{
    declare_func();
};

declare_func(MyClass) { }
```

PP_CAT is a classic multilevel concat macro

PP_NARG counts the number of macro arguments

PP_LEFT_PAREN and PP_RIGHT_PAREN reduce to '(' and ')'

Is there any way to achieve this with GCC ? ( I tried both macro version with GCC 5.2, both fail to compile because the comma seem to be propagated during macro resolution and removed only at the end of preprocessing, making PP_NARG always reduce to '2' and never '1')

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

> Second, the ‘##’ token paste operator has a special meaning when placed between a comma and a variable argument. If you write

```
 #define eprintf(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

> and the variable argument is left out when the eprintf macro is used, then the comma before the ‘##’ will be deleted. This does not happen if you pass **an empty argument**, nor does it happen if the token preceding ‘##’ is anything other than a comma.

```
 eprintf ("success!\n")
      ==> fprintf(stderr, "success!\n");
```

> The above explanation is ambiguous about the case where the only macro parameter is a variable arguments parameter, as it is meaningless to try to distinguish whether no argument at all is an empty argument or a missing argument. **In this case the C99 standard is clear that the comma must remain**, however the existing GCC extension used to swallow the comma. So CPP retains the comma when conforming to a specific C standard, and drops it otherwise.

So for

```
#define declare_func(...) _declare_func ( notused,##__VA_ARGS__ )
```

the comma remain in C standard, you may use `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu++11` to drop the comma and have your working macro.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f602dd0a7358c7ad)

To make your macro works with `-std=c++11`, you have so to force to have at least one argument.

Comment: You saved my day ! thank you a lot ! that did the job.. i was indeed using -std=c++11 instead of std=gnu++11.